# KonvaJs: Add border to Arrow

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs, konvajs

I am using [KonvaJS](http://konvajs.github.io/docs/) in my project. I need to have an arrow like this: [image]

The arrow will lie between two shapes. Shapes are draggable. Length of the arrow line should increase or decrease as user drags shapes. As a workaround I have used two instance of `Konva.Arrow` in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Em2OyYxH1sCOIj8uTPg8?p=preview). But I don't want to use two instances cause it will be difficult to manage their position when user will drag the shapes. I don't know how can I do so.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one way to do this is implement you own `Arrow` using `Konva.Shape` http://konvajs.github.io/docs/shapes/Custom.html

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks :)